# How to load full page includes master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

Please see below picture when I add Javascript loader, master page menu items does not... how to include this full page show loading... anyone help me ... please and also  one more question. I am using anchor tag in my menu items... how to change page page refresh?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           var imageID=0;
           function changeImage(){
               var div = document.getElementById('overlay');

               // hide
               div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           }

           //call same function again for x of seconds
           setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
       </script>
```

HTML//

```
 <div id="overlay">
            <div id="modalprogress">
                <div id="theprogress">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgWaitIcon" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="/images/loading.gif" />
                    Please wait...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details about your problem.

Comment: more details ??  i am using asp.net master page.. and asp.net webforms

Comment: @Ravikumar  check picture i added

Comment: Can you put this Loader code in Master page and try to Call that from child page.

Comment: how .................................?

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use update panel

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progress" runat="server" Updatemode="Conditional">
            <ProgressTemplate>
              <div id="overlay">
            <div id="modalprogress">
                <div id="theprogress">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgWaitIcon" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="/images/loading.gif" />
                    Please wait...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

JS:

function changeImage(){
           var div = document.getElementById('overlay');

```
       // hide
       div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
```

Call The function from BackEnd

```
 ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), 
        "changeImage()", true);
```

So it will not postback the page.

Comment: just change the style of "overlay" layer.